# react-carousel-slider doesn't rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

guys! Have a problem with rerendering of slider component. After choosing another SELECT option, other images are to be loaded to carousel component. But!! Nothing happens! Props of component are being changed, and developer tools show slides (images) are changed, but nothing happens on DOM.

Below i post code. What do you think? Where is the problem?

[image]

[image]

```js
import React from 'react';
import CarouselSlider from "react-carousel-slider";
import { FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';

class StampChoose extends React.Component {

    changeSamplesType = (e) => {
        const sampleType = e.target.value;
        this.props.changeSamplesType(sampleType);
        this.forceUpdate();
    }

    render() {
        let btnWrapperStyle = {
            position: "relative",
            borderRadius: "50%",
            height: "50px",
            width: "50px",
            textAlign: "center"
        }

        let btnStyle = {
            display: "inline-block",
            position: "relative",
            top: "90%",
            transform: "translateY(-50%)",
            fontSize: "36px"
        }


        let rBtnCpnt = (<div style = {btnWrapperStyle} >
            <div style = {btnStyle} className = "material-icons" >
                <i className="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
            </div>
        </div>);

        let lBtnCpnt = (<div style = {btnWrapperStyle} >
            <div style = {btnStyle} className = "material-icons" >
                <i className="fas fa-angle-left"></i>
            </div>
        </div>);  

        let iconItemsStyle = {
            padding: "0px",
            background: "transparent",
            margin:"0 5px",
            height: "80%"
        };

        const titles = this.props.titles;
        const slides = this.props.slides;
        
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                        <FormControl componentClass="select" onChange={ this.changeSamplesType }>
                            <option value="type1">{ titles['type1'] }</option>
                            <option value="type2">{ titles['type2'] }</option>
                            <option value="type3">{ titles['type3'] }</option>
                            <option value="type4">{ titles['type4'] }</option>
                        </FormControl>
                        <CarouselSlider 
                            sliderBoxStyle = {{height: "150px", width: "90%", background: "transparent", overflow: "hidden"}} 
                            accEle = {{dots: false}}
                            newState={ this.state }
                            slideCpnts = {slides} 
                            itemsStyle = {iconItemsStyle}
                            buttonSetting = {{placeOn: 'middle-outside'}}
                            rBtnCpnt = {rBtnCpnt}
                            lBtnCpnt = {lBtnCpnt}    
                        />

            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}


export default StampChoose;
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Grid, Row, Col, ControlLabel } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { samples, titles}  from '../../../samples-stamps';
import StampChoose from './StampChoose';


const Sample = (props) => (
    <React.Fragment>
        {
            <div>
                <img src={ `images/samples/${props.img}` } alt={ props.title } />
            </div>
        }
    </React.Fragment>
);


class StampsSamples extends React.Component {
    state = {
        sampleType: 'type1'
    }

    changeSamplesType = (sampleType) => {
        this.setState({ sampleType });
    }

    render() {
        const sampleType = this.state.sampleType;
        let slides = Object.keys(samples[sampleType]).map((item, i) => {
                    return (
                        <div>
                        <Sample 
                            key={i}
                            title={ samples[sampleType][item].title }
                            img={ samples[sampleType][item].img }
                            productId={ samples[sampleType][item].id }
                        />
                        </div>
                    );
            });

        return (
            <Grid>
                <Row>
                    <Col md={ 4 }>
                        <ControlLabel>Примерный образец оттиска <br/>
                            <small>(выберите образец оттиска)</small>
                        </ControlLabel>    
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={ 8 }>
                        <StampChoose 
                            slides={ slides }
                            titles={ titles }
                            changeSamplesType={ this.changeSamplesType }
                            />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Grid>
        ); 
    }
}

export default StampsSamples;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Sample Component your returning an object inside of React.Fragment. Does it have anything to do with that? What if you remove the { and } inside there and try? Like below. Don't know if thats the issue but try. You also have an extra DIV in your map method for the slides. If you check the instructions for the React Carousel Slider they dont use these extra DIVs and {}

```
 <React.Fragment>
   <div>
     <img src={ `images/samples/${props.img}` } alt={ props.title } />
   </div>   
 </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: I fot rid of all this extra DIVs and object in Sample. With rendering is all the same. But I agree it was little muddy. This way it's better. Tnx.

Comment: No worries. =) Does it render the slider images correctly on initial render? So you know that all data are correctly injected into the slider?

Comment: Yeah on first rendering all is well. And on change Select I see in devtools in props all is ok. So all goes as must except rendering new images. I am puzzled.

Comment: Ok ... hmmm .. strange. Hard to tell to just looking at it like this. The first thing I would do is remove the forceUpdate() ... you shouldn't need that anyway. Then do some console logging and check that the component actually updates. If it updates you know that theres something in the slider itself and not the component not updating.

Comment: Ok. Hope you find whats causing this. I actually put a lot of time in it to find out what it is but I can't track any faults. The only thing that i wonder about is what is newState={ this.state } in your CarouselSlider? You don't have any state in the component so it will always be null. One reason that a component don't update is also if the props somehow gets modified directly. So if something happens in the SliderCarousel component that modifies the props directly it won't re-render. 

I'm curios. So if you find the fault please let me know. =)

Comment: I didn't do anything useful with the component. So desided to use another component. This one https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel . It works as i want. What is wrong with react-carousel-slider i do not know. I gave up))))

Comment: Great to hear! Sometimes it's just like this ... but as long as you can find another working alternative it's just fine. =)